# How can I convert an excel file into CSV with batch skipping some rows?

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

I was asked to look for a procedure that convert an Excel file into a CSV one, however I have no knowledge on .bat. I've seen some people doing so with some commands and I would like to know if I can do the same but **important**: skipping the first five rows of the file.

I would appreciate any help you give me.

Comment: Have you tried just plain 'Save as CSV' from Excel. will that be okay? Or you want it scripted?

Comment: I need it to be scripted, yes.

Comment: You need to use a more suitable language, such as [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27293481), or [VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1858195). Alternatively use an executable utility designed for the task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A very easy way, is to create a vbs script. Paste the below into a notepad and save as `XlsToCsv.vbs`. Make sure you give the full path of `sourcexlsFile` and also `destinationcsvfile`

To use: `XlsToCsv.vbs [sourcexlsFile].xls [destinationcsvfile].csv`

```
 if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
End If
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.Sheets(1).Range("1:5").EntireRow.Delete  'this removes the first five rows everytime
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I must avoid in the possible to access the Excel file. And yet, there's the problem that I need to skip that first five rows everytime I execute it.

Comment: who is down votting without comments? Are you being helpful here? I have personally tried this code and it works.

Comment: I don't know who is down voting, but this worked for me too