# How to convert Excel xlsx file to xls file in batch by PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I am having multiple .xlsx file genrated from SAP BO4.2
But user reads .xls only so wanted to write some script which will convert .xlsx to .xls

Referred-
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-convert-Excel-xlsx-d9521619
and tried to use same for .xls

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

Function Convert-xlsInBatch
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$Folder
    )
    $ExcelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *.xlsx -Recurse

    $excelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excelApp.DisplayAlerts = $false

    $ExcelFiles | ForEach-Object {
        $workbook = $excelApp.Workbooks.Open($_.FullName)
        $xlsFilePath = $_.FullName -replace "\.xlsx$", ".xls"
        $workbook.SaveAs($xlsFilePath, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlExcel7)
        $workbook.Close()
    }

    # Release Excel Com Object resource
    $excelApp.Workbooks.Close()
    $excelApp.Visible = $true
    Start-Sleep 5
    $excelApp.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelApp)     | Out-Null
}

#
# 0. Prepare the folder path which contains all excel files
$FolderPath = "D:\XXX\AA\BB\Apr-2018"

Convert-XlsInBatch -Folder $FolderPath
```

Error I am getting-

```
PS D:\Batch Script> D:\Batch Script\ConvertExcelToXlsInBatch.ps1

New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed 
due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
At D:\Batch Script\ConvertExcelToXlsInBatch.ps1:27 char:14
+     $excelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Comment: The issue you have seems similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772500/powershell-cannot-create-outlook-com-object-from-command-prompt

Comment: @BenoîtMayer- In my system neither Outlook nor MS office is installed. Its just a server where file op is coming from Application and going to other location through Perl Scripts.

Comment: This is the issue: you cannot use ComObjects without having MS Office installed...

Comment: Is there any way I can convert file without having MS Office. BatchScript, ShellScript, perlscript anything will work. requirement is it should be proper conversion and not just extension rename/change.

Comment: To my knowledge it is not possible to convert xlsx files to xls without Excel installed, at least using Powershell, and I have been looking around for a long time.

Comment: You can convert from xlsx to csv using a module called ImportExcel though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293481/convert-multiple-xls-to-csv-using-powershell/56073900#56073900

Comment: Also if you just change the extension of a file from "csv" to "xls" (without any conversion), Excel will show an error message but will nonetheless open it correctly. It is not optimal but maybe it can be a good-enough solution.

Comment: Ok so instead of powershell can I use Perl? but I do not have MS Office or SpreadSheet installed on my Server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've seen this solution. It's 4 years old but it seems to work.

https://superuser.com/questions/875831/using-powershell-is-it-possible-to-convert-an-xlsx-file-to-xls

Comment: [Type]::Missing,$true)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\Batch Script\Convert.ps1:10 char:1
+ $Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath,56)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull