# Powershell converting xls hangs due to too much HTML data

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a Powershell script that receives an .xls file via email. Unfortunately the file can only be sent as an xls file, so the script converts it to a csv. This has been working perfectly in the past using the following code, which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293481/convert-multiple-xls-to-csv-using-powershell):

```
$ExcelWB = new-object -comobject excel.application
$BasePath = [directorypath]
$FilePath = (Get-ChildItem $BasePath -Filter "export*.xls").FullName
$Workbook = $ExcelWB.Workbooks.Open($FilePath) 
$Workbook.SaveAs($CsvPath,6)
$Workbook.Close($false)
$ExcelWB.quit()
```

This used to work in the past, and still does for the second xls file, but when running it on one of the files the command `$Workbook = $ExcelWB.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)` hangs and never completes. Killing the command is not even possible, and the only way to end it is to kill the Excel process in Task Manager.

When I open the file in Excel it throws this error:
[image: Excel error message]

The log file mentioned in the error message only has one line of data: `HTML ERROR in Cell data too large :`

There is one column in the xls that contains HTML data, and must contain HTML data. I see in [this article](https://www.davidtan.org/excel-cell-data-too-large-problem-and-solution/) that to fix this error you need to convert it to csv, which is already what I am trying to do.

Does anybody know how I might be able to convert the file from xls to csv despite this error?

Comment: Can you open the file by double clicking on the file?  Did somebody change the extension from xlsx to xls?  An xls file is Excel 2003 and has smaller limits than an xlsx file.  I suspect that the powershell comobject excel.application is using Excel 2003 instead of a new version of excel.

Comment: You may want to first confirm that it truly is an xls file instead of a renamed XML/HTML/xlsx file. `gc file.xls -Encoding Byte -TotalCount 8 | format-hex` googleing the magic number for xls says it should be `D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1`

Comment: @jdweng yes, I can open the file in the application, but it shows the error in the screenshot above. I can however view the data. The file is sent directly from a report, so it has not been modified by individual. The other xls files work perfectly using the method above

Comment: @Gregory The file is coming in directly from a report, but it might be possible that its a reformatted file of another type. Running `Get-Content .\export.02.07.2024.xls -AsByteStream -TotalCount 8 | Format-Hex` returns the following value: `3C 68 74 6D 6C 20 78 6D`. The Ascii value shows `<html xm`

Comment: Some web-based report generators skimped on writing xls files(proprietary binary file format), and it looks like this one is likely one of those. Try opening the xls file in a text editor. Excel will open lots of file types claiming to be xls as xls when in fact they are nothing more than imposters.

Comment: Looks like you may be onto something. I opened the xls in a text editor and it spit out a bunch of html text. It looks like I'll need to work on converting the html table to a csv. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody finding this question in the future, I did not find a perfect solution to this problem. The comments were correct in that the xls file was actually an html file in disguise, which was causing some confusions. But at the end of the day the column in question that exceeded the cell limit was actually being truncated, so it was not a usable file anyways. I had to coordinate with the person generating the file to fix the file export.

According to [this documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#:%7E:text=Total%20number%20of%20characters,32%2C767%20characters) the character limit is 32,767 characters. To see which record was causing the issue, I opened the xls file, copied it into a csv, import it into powershell, and then run the following:

```
$csv | foreach-object {
    if ($psitem.$ColumnName.length -ge 32767) {
        $psitem | select-object [property names to identify the record]
    }
}
```

I know this is not an ideal solution, but it helped me figure out the root cause so I figured I would share in hopes it may help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

There is so much that depends on what the format of the generated report is that YMMV, but if your source data file is small enough in bytes and rows this worked for me.

```
$d = gc file.xls -raw # html file pretending to be xls
$x = [xml]($d -replace '(?s)^.*?(<table>.*</table>).*?$','$1') # grab the table
$x.table.ChildNodes.foreach{ # each table row
   # use double-quotes in the csv when needed(see RFC-4180)
   $_.ChildNodes.InnerText.foreach{$_.replace('"','""') -replace '^(.*[",\n].*)$','"$1"'} -join ','
} | Set-Content file.csv
```